# JS - If Statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have the following piece of code in my JS application, however it doesn't work and I'm not seeing any errors in the debugging application either.

Can you tell me what I'm missing? Thanks!

```
function mouseActivity(e)
{
    if(e=='mousedown' || e=='touchstart') {
            mouseDown = true;
            var coords = calcCoordinates(couponCanvas, e);
            drawEventPath();
            return false;
    }
    if(e=='mousemove' || e=='touchmove'){

            if (!mouseDown)
                return true;
            var coords = calcCoordinates(couponCanvas, e);
            return false;
    }
    if(e=='mouseup' || e=='touchend'){
            if (mouseDown)
            {
                mouseDown = false;
                return false;
            }
            return true;            
    }
}
```

The above function will determine what actions to take on different mouse/touch events. It is being called from another function:

function dummy(){

```
    couponCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseActivity);
    couponCanvas.addEventListener('touchstart', mouseActivity);

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseActivity);
    window.addEventListener('touchmove', mouseActivity);

    window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseActivity);
    window.addEventListener('touchend', mouseActivity);
```

}

Comment: What means "doesn't work"?

Comment: when is this called and how?

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* How exactly doesn't it work? What do you expect it to do instead?

Comment: This code works perfectly. It will do all instructions on different cases. It works.

Comment: What's supposed to happen? What's happening instead? "it doesn't work" isn't an adequate problem statement.

Comment: Explain. What are you trying to do, what's happening instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing type in event, check for type

```
event.type;
```

Comment: So `if(e.type=='mousedown' || e.type=='touchstart') {` etc?

Comment: it should work then but main problem is code is missing to check the type of event instead check for whole event to be equal to something